# gwt mouse over events not fired when mouse button is down

Tags: events, gwt, mouse, mouseevent, smartgwt

When you push down the left mouse button mouse down event fires. If you then move the mouse over a label (while holding the mouse button down) mouse over event does not fire.

Is there any way to enable this events or fire them manualy or simulate them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are actually doing is two separate events, one is a mouse down event as you have described and the other is a mouse drag.

If you want to simulate them, that you might have to consider using a mouse click to track the user's (x,y) location. Subsequently, if you want to "simulate" it you could do some computation and decide for yourself if it is indeed a mouse click or mouse drag event that has occurred.

Hope it helps :) Cheers!